# Entity Background 'parallax image' positioning 'top' value issue when DOM is manipulated by other modules

Tags: 7, javascript

I am having an issue where the calculated value for the 'top' property that applied to the parallax-slider image is excessively large and pushing the image outside of the viewport.

```
<div class="parallax-mirror" style="visibility: visible; z-index: -100; position: fixed; top: 397px; left: 0px; overflow: hidden; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); height: 400px; width: 1209px;">
    <img class="parallax-slider" src="/sites/default/files/paragraphs/e_background/ct_1920_0.jpg" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px); position: absolute; top: 34946px; left: 0px; height: 755px; width: 1209px; max-width: none;">
</div>
```

In my case as you can see the 'top' property is **34946px** which is 5X the height of my page content (6502px). After some testing I (believe) I have narrowed it down to a result of other modules manipulating the DOM and giving a miscalculation.

I am using the Responsive Menu module as well as the Adminimal Theme and Menu modules which both manipulate the DOM and create various wrapping and spacing elements. Disabling these modules give me slightly different results (however still and issue) This seems like it must be a jQuery firing order issue and these other DOM changes are interfering with the parallax.js calculations?

To confirm I have tested the following:

- I have tested with versions 1.3.1 and the most recent 1.4.2 of the
  parallax.js library with the same result
- it is not a background colour issue :-p
- Disabling the Responsive Menu module and viewing as an anonymous user  the parallax image is still being miscalculated but the number is about 15K pixels less than my initial test.

Can anyone else confirm having issues with these or similar DOM altering modules?

Also How can I alter the module firing weight?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this issue, the real problem was not having a value in the 'speed' field.